# data parameter is nil error when checking internet connectivity

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When launching my app it checks if user is subscribed.  If it dosent detect an internet connection it crashes with the error:

`Failed to retrieve subscription with error 'The Internet connection appears to be offline.' and responseString: (null)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`

.m

```
  [self getPath:path
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
          {
              failureBlock(@"Invalid response received");
              return;
          }
          NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
          if (responseDict[@"error"] == nil)
          {
              [self saveUserDict:responseDict];
              successBlock(responseDict);
          }
          else
          {
              failureBlock(responseDict[@"error"]);
          }
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          DebugLog(@"Failed to log in with error '%@' and response: %@", error.localizedDescription, operation.responseString);
          failureBlock(@"An unknown error occurred");
      }];

 }



 - (void)getSubscriptionWithSuccessBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *subscriptionDict))successBlock
                       failureBlock:(void (^)(id responseObject))failureBlock
 {
static NSString *path = @"/api/subscription";

NSDictionary *parameters = @{
    @"userId" : userDict[@"userId"],
    @"token" : userDict[@"token"]
};

 DebugLog(@"Getting subscription with parameters: %@", parameters);



     [self getPath:path
     parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
          {
              failureBlock(@"Invalid response received");
              return;
          }
          NSDictionary *subscriptionDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
          if (subscriptionDict[@"error"] == nil)
          {
              DebugLog(@"Successfully retrieved subscription");
              successBlock(subscriptionDict);
          }
          else
          {
              failureBlock(responseObject);
          }
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          DebugLog(@"Failed to retrieve subscription with error '%@' and responseString: %@", error.localizedDescription, operation.responseString);
          id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:nil];
          failureBlock(responseObject);
      }];
    }
```

Comment: Well, the code that you posted only shows us what happens if it fails and how you print the error. We need to see what happens in your `getPath: parameters: success: failure:` method

Comment: Looks like you need to handle the error scenario before passing it onto JSONObjectWithData method. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the `error` before proceeding with the below line. In case there is an error do not call `JSONObjectWithData`: method with null data.

```
[self getPath:path
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
              {
                  failureBlock(@"Invalid response received");
                  return;
              }
              NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
              if (responseDict[@"error"] == nil)
              {
                  [self saveUserDict:responseDict];
                  successBlock(responseDict);
              }
              else
              {
                  failureBlock(responseDict[@"error"]);
              }
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              if (!error) {
                  DebugLog(@"Failed to retrieve subscription with error '%@' and responseString: %@", error.localizedDescription, operation.responseString);
                  id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];
                  failureBlock(responseObject);
              } else {
                  //handle the error scenario
                  failureBlock(@"error occured");
              }
          }];
```

Comment: keep geetting epected ":" error at first brace  for error scenario

Comment: Which line is showing that error? I have updated my answer. At the end of this }, it should have }];

Comment: sorry abou this but that gives me three errors http://cl.ly/image/2O0j171i2i3e is a screen shot of my screen

Comment: I am not able to see if (!error) {

    id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:nil];
    failureBlock(responseObject);
  } in your screenshot. Please check the code you copy pasted. Try replacing your code with the above code completely. you are missing the if condition in your code.

Comment: Can you please check this line "if (!error) {" is present in your code. Because in this screenshot also, I am not able to see this line, "if (!error) {".. I have added the complete thing in my code. Please check with that.

Comment: Ahhh! thats what I was missing, now it all makes sense!! thank you so much for your help and patience with this I owe you one! Big plus 1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

check for internet connection with [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) framework.